# ZeroDivisionError in message encoder/decoder on Python

Tags: python, tkinter, base64

Im doing a message Encoder/Decoder in Python, based on the one made by this website: https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-message-encode-decode/

Everything works fine, until i click to encode a message, and gives me this error on my terminal:

```
  File "C:\Users\Proyects\message_decode\main.py", line 26, in Encode
    key_c = key[i % len(key)]
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I've tried reading about this, but I have not found anything relevant.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import base64

root = Tk()

root.geometry('500x300')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Message Encode and Decode")

Label(root, text='ENCODE DECODE', font = 'arial 20 bold').pack()

Label(root, text= 'ZussM4n', font = 'arial 20 bold').pack(side = BOTTOM)

#defining variables
Text = StringVar()
private_key = StringVar()
mode = StringVar()
Result = StringVar()

#algoritmo encoder
def Encode(key, message):
    enc=[]

    for i in range(len(message)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        enc.append(chr((ord(message[i]) + ord(key_c)) % 256))
    return base64.urlsafe_bs64encode("".join(enc).encode()).decode()

#algoritmno decoder
def Decode(key, message):
    dec=[]
    message = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message).decode()

    for i in range(len(message)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        dec.append(chr(256 + ord(message[i]- ord(key_c)) % 256))
    return "".join(dec)

#function to set mode
def Mode():
    if(mode.get() == 'e' or 'E'):
        Result.set(Encode(private_key.get(),Text.get()))
    elif(mode.get() == 'd' or 'D'):
        Result.set(Decode(private_key.get(), Text.get()))
    else:
        Result.get('Invalid Mode')

#Exit
def Exit():
    root.destroy()

#Reset window
def Reset():
    Text.set("")
    private_key.set("")
    mode.set("")
    Result.set("")

#Labels and Buttons

Label(root, font= 'arial 12 bold', text='MESSAGE').place(x= 60,y=60)
Entry(root, font = 'arial 10', textvariable = Text, bg = 'ghost white').place(x=290, y = 60)

Label(root, font = 'arial 12 bold', text ='KEY').place(x=60, y = 90)
Entry(root, font = 'arial 10', textvariable = private_key , bg ='ghost white').place(x=290, y = 90)

Label(root, font = 'arial 12 bold', text ='MODE(e-encode, d-decode)').place(x=60, y = 120)
Entry(root, font = 'arial 10', textvariable = mode , bg= 'ghost white').place(x=290, y = 120)
Entry(root, font = 'arial 10 bold', textvariable = Result, bg ='ghost white').place(x=290, y = 150)

Button(root, font = 'arial 10 bold', text = 'RESULT'  ,padx =2,bg ='LightGray' ,command = Mode).place(x=60, y = 150)

Button(root, font = 'arial 10 bold' ,text ='RESET' ,width =6, command = Reset,bg = 'LimeGreen', padx=2).place(x=80, y = 190)

Button(root, font = 'arial 10 bold',text= 'EXIT' , width = 6, command = Exit,bg = 'OrangeRed', padx=2, pady=2).place(x=180, y = 190)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: well apparently length of `k` is `0`

Comment: No, i suppose it would be 0 if there were no characters inserted, wich there are.

Comment: the error tells that `key` has a length of `0`, meaning that the string is empty, that's it, it is empty

Comment: also the usage of `or` is incorrect, they will always evaluate to True since any non-empty string is truthy here: `mode.get() == 'e' or 'E'`, the better probably is to use `mode.get().lower() == 'e'` and also those parentheses are redundant, also usually you would want to use `pack` or `grid` not `place`